# Slide out side toolbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I have seen on some websites now there is a small strip down the side of the page and when you hover over the strip it slides out and shows more information.

Here is where I have seen the bar in action:

http://kabx.net/uk/

On the left hand side when you hover, it will expand out.

I wanted to see what this is called and how I can achieve this effect?

I have searched for different things like 'Slideing Toolbar' and other things but i cant seem to find the name.

EDIT:

```
                <hr class="line" />
                <hr class="line1" />
                <hr class="line1" />

                <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Tick.png" ID="IMG_Tick" />
                <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Cross.png" ID="IMG_Cross" />
                <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Text.png" ID="IMG_Text" />

            </div>
```

This is my div is it possible to say when its on hover to delete these images and when its not to brring them back?

Comment: [google search](https://www.google.co.in/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=how+to+slide+out+sidebar+using+css+or+js&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&safe=active&gfe_rd=cr&ei=QB6gU_HHG6fV8gfW6IDgCg&gws_rd=ssl)

Comment: it seems the website uses mouseover event to trigger the action of changing the style of its header

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pure CSS and HTML. Although you can go for harder things and use javascript.

The logic of the CSS is to set the sidebar element absolute positioned to the left, and with some negative value in order to get rid of it.
Then use the :hover selector and set a new value for the `left: -###;` property, and the sidebar will come back once you mouse-over part of the sidebar (supposing you didn't completely hide it)

Edit: Take this JSFiddle and read the comments I've done there.

### http://jsfiddle.net/NGL8v/2/

Tell me if you don't understand something

Comment: If you would that would be great!

Comment: Thanks, I dont understand how to get the Roses are Red bit to appear only on hover?

Comment: Roses are Red appear only when you hover part of the sidebar, because the whole sidebar appears from the left already.
You can see that on the line number 13 of the CSS square, in the JSFiddle

Comment: +1 for nice coding example.  I hope lots o' people use it and give you credit.

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/dHvYz/1/)**</kbd>

HTML

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li id="link-one">
      <div>1</div>
      <div>One</div>
    </li>
    <li id="link-two">
      <div>2</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </li>
    <li id="link-three">
      <div>3</div>
      <div>Three</div>
    </li>
    <li id="link-four">
      <div>4</div>
      <div>Four</div>
    </li>
    <li id="link-five">
      <div>5</div>
      <div>Five</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div id="one" class="desktop">
  <h1>Sidebar Example</h1>
  <p>This is 1</p>
  <p>Something here.</p>
</div>
<div id="two" class="desktop">
  <h1>Two</h1>
  <p>This is 2</p>
  <p>Some texts.</p>
</div>
<div id="three" class="desktop">
  <h1>Three</h1>
  <p>This is 3</p>
  <p>Some more texts here.</p>
</div>
<div id="four" class="desktop">
  <h1>Four</h1>
  <p>This is 4</p>
  <p>Texts here.</p>
</div>
<div id="five" class="desktop">
  <h1>Five</h1>
  <p>This is 5</p>
  <p>Contents here.</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:400,300);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300);
*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
  background: grey;
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 3.5rem;
  height: 100%;
  background: #2680f3;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #333;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #333;
}
nav:hover {
  width: 14rem;
}
nav * {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
nav > ul {
  display: table;
  width: 14rem;
}
nav > ul > li {
  display: table-row;
  background: #0c66da;
  cursor: pointer;
}
nav > ul > li:hover {
  background: #569cf6;
}
nav > ul > li:active {
  background: #87b9f8;
}
nav > ul > li > div {
  height: 3.5rem;
  line-height: 3.5rem;
  display: table-cell;
}
nav > ul > li > div:nth-child(1) {
  width: 3.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}
nav > ul > li > div:nth-child(2) {
  width: 10.5rem;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 0.7rem;
}

.desktop {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 1rem 1rem 1rem 4.5rem;
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
  transition: all 500ms ease;
  overflow: auto;
}
.desktop h1 {
  margin: 1rem 0;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.desktop h1:nth-child(1) {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.desktop p {
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: justify;
  margin: 0 0 1rem 0;
}
```

Javascript

```
var desktops = document.querySelectorAll('.desktop');

function hide(element) {
  element.style.setProperty('left', '-100%', element.style.getPropertyPriority('left'));
}

function hideAll() {
  for (var i = 0; i < desktops.length; i++) {
    hide(desktops[i]);
  }
}

function show(element) {
  element.style.setProperty('left', '0', element.style.getPropertyPriority('left'));
}

document.getElementById('link-one').addEventListener('click', function () {
  hideAll();
  show(document.getElementById('one'));
}, false);

document.getElementById('link-two').addEventListener('click', function () {
  hideAll();
  show(document.getElementById('two'));
}, false);

document.getElementById('link-three').addEventListener('click', function () {
  hideAll();
  show(document.getElementById('three'));
}, false);

document.getElementById('link-four').addEventListener('click', function () {
  hideAll();
  show(document.getElementById('four'));
}, false);

document.getElementById('link-five').addEventListener('click', function () {
  hideAll();
  show(document.getElementById('five'));
}, false);

show(document.getElementById('one'));
```

Comment: This comes up with an error 'JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'addEventListener' of undefined or null reference'

Comment: Just a Side Throw in...was thinking how it wud respond for a Mobile Device, the on hover works perfectly for a Desktop plaform.
  I tested it on my Note3 and its works great..as in, when u touch it it comes out.  Would it possible for you to integrate a Draggable function when on a Mobile platform instead...like the notification drawer pull down effect on mobiles